# Struts2 Annotation-Validators for Invalid Chars

Tags: struts2, annotations, validation, invalid-characters

While using Struts2, I am using several annotations to do my validations inside the Model class, in the `set()` methods, like:

```
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "Name is required")
@StringLengthFieldValidator(message = "Name must be between 5 and 60 characters", 
                              minLength = "5", maxLength = "60")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

But I would like how to put a validation do avoid Strange characters, like `!`, `?`, `#`, `$` and etc...

Is there any existing validator I should use like a `@RestrictChars` or maybe is there some way to use the `@StringRegexValidator`. Or should I write a new one. Any hint or documentation how to do such would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it finally:

Just adding the already existent `@RegexFieldValidator` gave me the Validator I needed:

```
@RegexFieldValidator(message = "Use only Letters or numbers",
                       expression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
```

Thanks anyway guys!